# Add all properties of a class to an object without any reinitiating in Typescript

Tags: typescript, casting, properties

I have the following code:

```
class Item {
    firstname : string;
    lastname : string;

    getFullName() : string {
        return this.firstname + " " + this.lastname;
    }
}

let obj : object = {firstname : "Foo", lastname: "Bar"};

let item : Item = obj as Item;

console.log(item.getFullName());
```

The above example throws an Exception, because `obj` doesn't know the function `getFullName()`, because I just told the compiler, that the `obj` object should be an `Item`, but it is not.

Is it possible to transform the `obj` object into an `Item` object, so the `getFullName()` is properly assigned to `obj` without reinitiating an `Item`?

I receive nested objects via JSON and I don't want to loop through all of them, just to create the corresponding class objects.

I want to map the properties of the received object onto the class object on the fly, just like *casting* it, but add all the missing properties and functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) won't ever have this functionality. Type casting explicitly tells the compiler the type of the object, but it won't actually change that object. This is what the constructor function was made to do, however.

You can use the constructor as a factory function and pass a configuration object. Then, use the body of the constructor function to set default values in case certain properties aren't provided. Method creation will be handled for you.

```
class Item {
    firstname : string;
    lastname : string;

    getFullName() : string {
        return this.firstname + " " + this.lastname;
    }

    constructor(obj: Partial<Item>) {
      this.firstname = obj.firstname || '';
      this.lastname = obj.lastname || '';
    }
}
```

Now you can create new instances of an item from an object like this:

```
let obj : object = {firstname : "Foo", lastname: "Bar"};
let item = new Item(obj);
```

I used the `Partial` type here to allow you to use any configuration for your new item. You can create items without providing all the necessary properties in the config object, and it will automatically assign them for you. E.g.

```
let item2 = new Item({firstname: 'Foo'});
```

You don't need to cast it now because `item` and `item2` are actually of type `Item`.

Read more about Partial types here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html.